# getting error when i try to use "react-native-dom "--error Unrecognized command "dom"

Tags: windows, react-native, uwp, drm, playready

I have followed documentation

```
 yarn add --dev rnpm-plugin-dom

 react-native dom
```

error
error Unrecognized command "dom".[image]

Answer (score -1):

you are writing the command in the wrong way. here it is:

```
yarn add --dev rnpm-plugin-dom

react-native-dom
```

Comment: not worked ....'react-native-dom' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: did you installed the react-native-dom dependency? it is shown in the package.json file

Comment: yes... i see a entry under dev dependency in package.json @haseeb